# Brother network printer with users

Tags: networking, printing, users

My office has a Brother MFC-9970 CDW on the network.  The printer is set up with users so that each person can be billed according to their printing usage.  Everyone can print from Windows, but from Ubuntu I can't find out **where to put my user name and password**. I am beginning to wonder if it is possible.

Here is an excerpt from my /var/log/cups file:

> localhost - - [27/Oct/2014:15:59:47 -0400] "POST /printers/Brother-MFC-9970CDW HTTP/1.1" 200 55960 Print-Job successful-ok

and the same print job from CUPS `http://localhost:631/jobs?which_jobs=completed:`

> Brother-MFC-9970CDW-1263   Unknown     Withheld    55k     Unknown     completed at
>   Mon 27 Oct 2014 03:59:52 PM EDT

The job did *not* print, the printer just gave a message "function locked".

Anyone have an idea?  Thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/316331/where-to-set-account-tracking-in-cups-printing seems to be the way to do it.  `/etc/cups/ppd/{your_printer_id}.ppd`

Comment: Thanks +Rinzwind, I will try to figure all that out, and next time I'm at the office hopefully I will be able to print!  Do you think it would be possible to convince the CUPS team to integrate that to make it a bit more user-friendly? :)

Comment: they probably consider this to be very user friendly (in that nobody ever wants it so they tug it away as deep as possible and if you do want it your mistake ;) ). j/k

Answer (score 0):

Hope you using CUPS for printing.

Go to the page `http://localhost:631`

Once you are on this page, click on “Administrator”, and then click on “Add Printer.” You might be asked for username and password of your computer.

Once after updating username and password try printing the job.

**For the error "function locked" please Turn off Secure Function Lock**

If your Brother machine has a touchscreen, please follow the steps of "For Touchscreen models" below.

- Press Menu.
- Press the Up or Down Arrow key choose Lock On->Off and press OK.
- Enter your four-digit administrator password and press OK.

**FOR models Touchscreen**

- Press image.
- Press Lock On->Off.
- Enter your four-digit administrator password by pressing the buttons
  on the Touchscreen and press OK.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Vembu, but I can't turn it off, the office _needs_ to have it on to track how much each user is printing.  Rinzwind understood better what I want to do.  Now it's just to get that working... :P